# Replace double quotes with quote_space_quote

Tags: c#, string, formatting

I want the code of replacing `""` with `" "` while writing in TextBox..

For example, when the user enters `""` in the TextBox1, it must be converted in "(space here)"

I have tried this code:

```
private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("""", "" "");
}
```

But it doesn't work because of syntax error with `""""`
So, which is the correct code.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the inner quotes:

```
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("\"\"", "\" \"");
```

Now the compiler recognizes the `"` as the start or end of a string, not the actual `"` character.

Answer (score 2):

You can always [escape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) `"` as `\"`

```
TextBox1.Text.Replace("\"\"", "\" \"");
```

Or you can use [verbatim string literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) with doubling them;

```
TextBox1.Text.Replace(@"""""", @""" """);
```